# How to display rank in MySQL 5.7 without using rank() and partiotion

Tags: mysql

Convert to mysql5.7
Select category, brands, revenue,
Rank() over (partition by category order by revenue) 'rank'
From task.ranking
Order by category

Comment: You must do your homework by yourself. PS. Use user-defined variables.

Comment: @shalu, this needs to be formatted in the form of a question rather than a task from an assignment.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to create a temporary table and compile the rank using a looping cursor with a greater-than comparison and then storing the result in a variable for display once the loop concludes.